# Count and print even flowers

Tags: java

We have n number of flowers that can be black or white. We have m number of months. At the end of each month, if the number of white flowers is even, we print B for the number of roses that are even, and print F for the rest of the characters.For example:(W=white,B=black)

input:3(n)  2(m)

WBW

BBW

output:FBB

My code just work well just for this example and dont give true answer for other examples.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of flowers: ");
    int flower = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of months : ");

    int month = input.nextInt();
    String[] arr = new String[month];
    char ch = ' ';
    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < month; j++)
        arr[j] = input.next();


    for (int i = 0; i < month; i++) {
        char[] s = arr[i].toCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < flower; j++) {
            if (s[j] == 'W') {
                count++;
            }

        }

        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            for (int k = 0; k < flower - count; k++) {
                System.out.print('F');
            }
                    for (int b = 1; b <= count; b++) {
                        System.out.print('B');
                    }


                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `How can i fix it?` Breakpoints, debug sessions in the IDE, and unit tests.

Comment: What _other examples_ do you have?

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < flower; j++) {
    if (s[j] == 'W') {
        count++;
    }
}
```

We must remember what s is referring to, `char[] s = arr[i].toCharArray();` which means that s will not have a length of `flower` but will have a length of `arr[i].length()` or `s.length`.
So if you change the for loop to use that as its control, it should solve the index out of bounds exception that you get.

The fix would look like:

```
for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
    if (s[j] == 'W') {
        count++;
    }
}
```